# Google Visualization API Web Query with Dates in where clause

Tags: sql, google-visualization, google-data-api

I have a google spreadsheet that has data in it like so:

```
11/3/2000   0.1 0.1673
11/3/2000   0.15    0.1734
11/3/2000   0.2 0.1786
11/3/2000   0.25    0.1834
11/3/2000   0.3 0.1879
11/3/2000   0.35    0.1924
....
```

And I am using the google visualization API to plot it.  I want to write a query like this:

```
var queryStr = "SELECT A,C WHERE B=" + delta + " AND A>='2005/04/04' ORDER BY A";
```

Basically I want to select a date range in the spreadsheet.  The above query returns no results, but there is data in the file that satisfies the query.  I tried changing it all around and the date format but no results.  How do I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wanted:

```
var queryStr = "SELECT A,C WHERE B=" + delta + " AND date '2005-04-04' < A ORDER BY A";
```

Google's vast documentation has only one example, but I found it.